# How do I sign in a user in Clearance from a custom router?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, clearance

I'm adding Omniauth to my app where I'm using Clearance for regular authentication.  I've run into a wall trying to sign in a user programatically.

I'm looking for something like `sign_in_and_redirect` from Devise, but can't find it in Clearance.

I've tried using `sign_in <User>` and calling `redirect_to root_path` right after.  However, when the root page loads, the `current_user` is not set.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Does anyone know of a tutorial for adding Omniauth to Clearance?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used Clearance, I usually either roll my own authentication or use Devise, but a quick look through the code tells me that sign_in(@user) does nothing more than set @current_user=@user so you need some way to persist that information before you redirect. Clearance appears to use a remember_token for this, so I'd try (untested) something like this:

```
sign_in(@user)
cookies['remember_token'] = @user.remember_token
redirect_to(root_path)
```